# convert tuple with unicode, decimal and date object to string in python

Tags: python, mysql

I get a tuple when i fetch data from MySql. I want to convert it to String so that i can display it in Table.

This is the tuple:

```
(u'1854-563', u'ROME', Decimal('5555'), datetime.date(2013, 3, 15))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> t = (u'1854-563', u'ROME', Decimal('5555'), datetime.date(2013, 3, 15))

>>> map("{0}".format,t)
['1854-563', 'ROME', '5555', '2013-03-15']
```

Or to make a table:

```
>>> r"<table><tbody>{0}</tbody></table>".format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td></tr>".format(*map("{0}".format,t)))
'<table><tbody><tr><td>1854-563</td><td>ROME</td><td>5555</td><td>2013-03-15</td></tr></tbody></table>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print '%s' % u'1854-563'
1854-563
>>> print '%s' % u'ROME'
ROME
>>> print '%s' % Decimal('5555')
5555
>>> print '%s' % datetime.date(2013, 3, 15)
2013-03-15
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to, they are essentially the same thing:

```
>>> mytup = (u'1854-563', u'ROME', Decimal('5555'), datetime.date(2013, 3, 15))
>>> mytup = tuple(str(i) if isinstance(i,unicode) else i for i in mytup)
>>> print mytup
('1854-563', 'ROME', Decimal('5555'), datetime.date(2013, 3, 15))
```